# Move from UIViewController to SKcene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I need help moving from a UIViewController that appears after launch. It is sort of a fake splash screen that is animated and I want it to change to the SKScene once done. I have tried using this,

```
let skView = self.view as SKView
    var loading:LevelOne = LevelOne(size: skView.bounds.size)
    var loadingScreen:SKView = self.view as SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.showsPhysics = true
    loadingScreen.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    loadingScreen.presentScene(loading)
```

But I get a log with (lldb) and it marks out

```
let skView = self.view as SKView
```

and says the app crashes due to that. What am I doing wrong and is there anybody who can help me out? I can convert Objective-c (simple that is) but I will prefer it in Swift

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can you build you game with this line?

```
let skView = self.view as SKView
```

Because you can not downcast from SKView? to SKView. I think it should be

```
let skView = self.view as SKView!
```

One another, can you go to storyboard, check the view of ViewController. The view should be an instance of SKView instead of UIView as a normal application (You can see it in "Custom Class" session of "Show the identity inspector")

Comment: It works. I couldn't get it to earlier then I re-did my game and cam here and it worked great :)